Calculate dimension of minipage from argument with `\dimexpr`
I want to create a new environment that scales the content of a frame in beamer. To this purpose, I define a new enviroment resize which takes an argument, used as scaling factor. I use the same variable to modify the width of the minipage.
Here is a MWE:
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{environ}
 \NewEnviron{resize}[1]{%
   \scalebox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth/#1\relax}\BODY\end{minipage}}}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{First slide}
   \begin{resize}{1.1}
     \lipsum[1]
   \end{resize}
 \end{frame}
      
 \end{document}
 

In particular, the expression \dimexpr\textwidth/#1\relax doesn't seem to work.

\dimexpr\textwidth*10/11 works.  I suspect the parser is having problems with the deimal point.

You can also use \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\wider}{\textwidth/#1} from the pgfmath package.

scaling text this way is among the top ten most heinous crimes against typography ;). more seriously, it really is a bad idea to introduce this kind of inconsistency in font sizes.

You can do this.(see also footnote 1 at bottom)
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{resize}[1]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{%
    \dimexpr
    \numexpr\textwidth*65536/\dimexpr#1pt\relax\relax
    sp\relax}\BODY\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Minus Two slide}
  \begin{resize}{0.8}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Minus One slide}
  \begin{resize}{0.9}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Zeroth slide}
  \begin{resize}{1}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First slide}
  \begin{resize}{1.1}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second slide}
  \begin{resize}{1.2}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Third slide}
  \begin{resize}{1.3}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Fourth slide}
  \begin{resize}{1.4}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{resize}
\end{frame}
     
\end{document}

Explanation: we first use \dimexpr#1pt\relax which inside a \numexpr context will give some integer N which is approximatively the value of decimal #1 times 65536 (as 1pt=65536sp). Then we use the fact (see e-TeX manual) that a multiplication in \numexpr can provisorily exceed the 2^31 upper bound if followed by an (integer) division.  Finally we reconvert from integer to decimal using the idiom \dimexpr Msp\relax.
Note: the 65536 could be replaced by \p@ if we were in "@ is letter" context.







[^1]: you might prefer \fpeval interface nowadays, which comes built-in LaTeX, but this will never beat the efficency of above approach.

the external \dimexpr and final \relax is not strictly necessary in this context (but if you remove \dimexpr do remove also \relax).

The syntax of \dimexpr allows <length>/<factor>, but the <factor> must be an integer.
Your problem is to compute the inverse of the scaling argument, which is easy to do with \fpeval.
No environ necessary.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{resize}{m}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\fpeval{1/(#1)}\textwidth}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \scalebox{#1}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First slide}

\begin{resize}{1.1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{resize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

You can also avoid boxing, but I don't see why.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{resize}{m +b}{%
  \scalebox{#1}{\begin{minipage}{\fpeval{1/(#1)}\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First slide}

\begin{resize}{1.1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{resize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you, but it seems that \fpeval requires a package, I guess xfp

@Massimo Only if your TeX system isn't up-to-date.

Then, I guess that my 2021 version of TeXlive is outdated....
